# wamp rewrite_module not getting ticked

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

I am using Windows 8.1, 64-bit architecture. Installed wamp and tried to run `mod_rewrite` module using tick option as shown in following image and with `httpd.conf` too but nothing working.

Instread of ✓ there is exclamation in red triangle, what is the reason?

[image]

Apache error log:

```
[Wed Apr 13 14:24:34.380769 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5436:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 14:24:34.380769 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5436:tid 536] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 14:24:34.380769 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5436:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 14:24:34.396347 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5436:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5920
[Wed Apr 13 14:24:35.168729 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5920:tid 468] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 15:53:59.967414 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5920:tid 956] [client ::1:50468] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:27.128177 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5436:tid 536] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:30.326308 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5920:tid 468] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:35.829329 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5436:tid 536] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5920 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:55.171128 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1140:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:55.171128 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1140:tid 536] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:55.171128 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1140:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:55.171128 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1140:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6588
[Wed Apr 13 15:54:55.804938 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 15:57:09.926493 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 972] [client ::1:50510] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 15:58:01.215411 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 944] [client ::1:50518] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:00:48.860542 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 968] [client ::1:50562] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:01:11.127785 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 944] [client ::1:50570] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:05:48.625053 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 972] [client ::1:50632] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:06:57.134940 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 944] [client ::1:50644] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:07:03.372989 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 944] [client ::1:50645] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:19:14.714062 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 944] [client ::1:50852] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:19:23.384688 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 956] [client ::1:50853] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 16:25:06.662434 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 972] [client ::1:50890] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 18:51:10.543623 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 968] [client ::1:51785] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 18:58:08.491111 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6588:tid 956] [client ::1:52470] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:30.987871 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1140:tid 536] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:32.992780 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 448] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:33.230151 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1140:tid 536] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6588 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:39.110705 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 544] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:39.110705 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 544] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:39.110705 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5812:tid 544] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:39.114087 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 544] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5516
[Wed Apr 13 19:49:39.638351 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5516:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 19:50:12.256444 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5516:tid 980] [client ::1:53405] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 19:50:13.432227 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5516:tid 976] [client ::1:53406] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 19:50:27.754298 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5516:tid 968] [client ::1:53413] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:15.837548 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 544] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:17.844880 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5516:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:18.002725 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 544] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5516 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:27.766595 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4696:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:27.767622 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4696:tid 536] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:27.767622 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4696:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:27.768883 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4696:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4784
[Wed Apr 13 19:59:28.208065 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4784:tid 468] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 20:02:24.795359 2016] [core:alert] [pid 4784:tid 968] [client ::1:50228] C:/wamp/www/ucc-v2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:01.532809 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4696:tid 536] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:03.545994 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4784:tid 468] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:03.629069 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4696:tid 536] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4784 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:04.778234 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 540] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:04.778234 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 540] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:04.778234 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6588:tid 540] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:04.779237 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 540] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5316
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:05.278878 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5316:tid 460] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:20.944723 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 540] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:22.957336 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5316:tid 460] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:22.981584 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 540] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5316 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:23.657412 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5820:tid 544] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:23.658511 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5820:tid 544] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:23.658511 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5820:tid 544] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:23.659337 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5820:tid 544] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4960
[Wed Apr 13 20:06:24.301556 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4960:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:07.212871 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5820:tid 544] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:09.226164 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4960:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:09.245863 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5820:tid 544] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4960 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:09.845602 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1308:tid 532] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:09.845602 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1308:tid 532] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:09.845602 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1308:tid 532] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:09.848613 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1308:tid 532] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5004
[Wed Apr 13 20:07:10.333504 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5004:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 20:08:59.198064 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1308:tid 532] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 20:09:01.201023 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5004:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 20:09:01.217151 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1308:tid 532] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5004 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 20:09:01.770738 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 532] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 20:09:01.771739 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 532] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 20:09:01.771739 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3324:tid 532] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 20:09:01.772633 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 532] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3152
[Wed Apr 13 20:09:02.304263 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3152:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:21.811276 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 532] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:23.814831 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3152:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:23.859842 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 532] AH00430: Parent: Child process 3152 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:37.057539 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3132:tid 552] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:37.057539 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3132:tid 552] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:37.057539 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3132:tid 552] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:37.059658 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3132:tid 552] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5996
[Wed Apr 13 20:15:37.536777 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5996:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:08.596660 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 980] [client ::1:50524] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:08.608609 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50525] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/ucc-v2
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:09.587894 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50526] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:09.599897 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50527] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/ucc-v2
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:16.061761 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50528] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:16.073197 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50530] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.040760 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50531] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.052762 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50532] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.557225 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50533] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.569228 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50534] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.761210 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50535] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.772640 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50536] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.950710 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50537] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:18.967196 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50538] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.155330 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50539] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.170395 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50540] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.342138 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50541] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.353690 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50542] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.592478 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50543] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.606773 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50544] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.797794 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50545] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.809795 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50546] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:19.990863 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50547] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:20.011439 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50548] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:46.123621 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50550] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:46.135629 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50551] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:46.629077 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50552] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:46.651350 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50553] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:46.867008 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50554] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:46.879007 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50555] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:47.071598 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50556] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:47.083598 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50557] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:47.272677 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50558] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:47.288604 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50559] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:47.449853 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 964] [client ::1:50560] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:17:47.460985 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 960] [client ::1:50561] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:24.880583 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50565] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:24.923417 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50566] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:25.608505 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50567] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:25.640490 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50568] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:25.810860 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50569] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:25.842861 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50570] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:25.997634 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50571] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:26.028602 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50572] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:26.176242 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50573] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:26.206190 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50574] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:26.389655 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50575] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Apr 13 20:18:26.433658 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5996:tid 972] [client ::1:50576] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:03.290666 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3132:tid 552] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:05.320841 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5996:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:05.503504 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3132:tid 552] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5996 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:10.933315 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2596:tid 220] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:10.934334 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2596:tid 220] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:10.934334 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2596:tid 220] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:10.935322 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2596:tid 220] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2944
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:11.342703 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2944:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:19.020490 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2596:tid 220] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:21.029478 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2944:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:21.070316 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2596:tid 220] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2944 exited successfully.
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:26.963578 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 684:tid 532] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:26.963578 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 684:tid 532] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:26.963578 2016] [core:notice] [pid 684:tid 532] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:26.966589 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 684:tid 532] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6060
[Wed Apr 13 20:36:27.505102 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6060:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: did you check the error log?

Comment: maybe this? http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,125976,125976

Comment: Please check apache error log.

Comment: Are you really sure that there is no documentation of those icons meaning?

Comment: @arkascha I researched alot but nothing is working, I am very new to this thing.

Comment: @andrew adn naf4me I added log, but I am very new to this thing and don't understand how to fix